# issue with deleting unix file

Tags: unix

Can someone please help me with this:

As seen below I have a file and directory with the same name as "sp"

How do I delete the file "sp" the one with 44673Bytes size

```
opxnyd@opxzone1d:/opt/opxnyd/packages/OPXPNY3DB/src/OPXPNYP>ls -alrt 
-rwxr-xr-x   1 opxnyd   opics      44673 Sep  7  2011 sp
drwxr-xr-x   4 opxnyd   opics       1974 May 10 10:22 sp
```

Comment: please tell me how did you create them, that will be a cool trick to play on someother's dir,

Comment: Jokester, think about shell quoting.

Comment: not sure how  ?? but might have got created accidently, unknowingly..

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that they don't actually have the same name.  one of them has a blank or non-printing character in the name.  Try `ls --escape` to see.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a directory and file with the same name. One of them would be probably having a white-space or some other non printable character in it.

Take this example:

```
$ touch "sp"
$ mkdir "sp "
$ ls -lrt
total 2
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    0 May 18 15:47 sp
drwxr-xr-x  2 user  staff   68 May 18 15:47 sp
```

#### To delete just the file you can use following find command:

```
find -E . -depth 1 -type f -regex "\./sp[ \t]*" -exec rm {} \;
```

OR following rm command:

```
\rm -i sp\ *
```

Comment: Be careful here, as this will delete any file with the prefix 'sp' -- worse, if you leave off the -depth it will get the files in any directory below `.`.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: `this will delete any file with the prefix 'sp' in any directory below` Please notice `-depth 1` in the find command. However I made an edit to my find command to make sure only filename starting with `sp` and whitespace gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Like Charlie Martin said, they dont actually have the same name. But you could do a `rm sp*` without -r option (directory), deleting only the file.

Comment: Be careful here, as this will delete any file with the prefix 'sp'.

Comment: @Charlie Martin No. Only the file. Use rm without -r: Create a file and a directory (anyone with a space in the name). Run 'rm *'. Directory willn't be deleted.

Comment: @Charlie Martin All 'sp' file will be deleted, yes. But his 'ls' show only two objects! Directory willn't be deleted without -r. Thanks everybody for -1. Next time, open a terminal and try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file (any of them, then) delete the one you don't want (and rename again, if you happed to rename the folder)